How can I express if the plans still the same?
Explain whether the plans are still on top? For example, a trip. If the plans to travel in a specific period didn’t change.

"The plans are still the same" is fine (you do need "are" in there). It's idiomatic. There are many other ways to express it, so you'll need to give more guidance if you want an alternative.

Well done for the example, that makes this question work. For your information "the plans are still on top" makes no sense, without the rest of the question I genuinely would not have known what you meant. Is this a word for word translation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"The plans are still on top" is not an idiomatic usage, but it hints at one that is: There's a meaning of "on" to mean "intended or planned" (see adjective 4 here. So "the plans are still on" means they are still planned to happen.

You could say

Our plans are unchanged.
Our plans have not changed.
Our plans remain the same.
We are not changing our plans.
We still intend to carry out our plan [note the singular "plan": if it's not a trip but a strategy].

